# How to get individual field names of compound field from EntityParticle object using Tooling API?

Tags: custom-field, tooling-api

```
SELECT  DataType,
        EntityDefinition.DeveloperName,
        IsCompound,
        DeveloperName,
        FieldDefinition.QualifiedApiName 
FROM    EntityParticle 
WHERE   EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName ='Account'
```

When I run the above query using Tooling API, it is printing all the fields present on Account object as below:

```
DATATYPE      ENTITYDEFINITION.DEVELOPERNAME ISCOMPOUND DEVELOPERNAME                    FIELDDEFINITION.QUALIFIEDAPINAME
───────────── ────────────────────────────── ────────── ──────────────────────────────── ─────────────────────────────────────
textarea      Account                                   BillingAddress                   BillingAddress
string        Account                                   BillingAddress                   BillingAddress
string        Account                                   BillingAddress                   BillingAddress
string        Account                                   BillingAddress                   BillingAddress
string        Account                                   BillingAddress                   BillingAddress
picklist      Account                                   BillingAddress                   BillingAddress
picklist      Account                                   BillingAddress                   BillingAddress
double        Account                                   BillingAddress                   BillingAddress
double        Account                                   BillingAddress                   BillingAddress
picklist      Account                                   BillingAddress                   BillingAddress
address       Account                        true       BillingAddress                   BillingAddress
```

How can I adjust the above query so that fields like `BillingStreet`, `BillingState` appear in the output?

I am open to other options if they can satisfy these requirements:

- Should return fields even if running user(System Admin) doesn't have FLS to those fields.(`sfdx force:schema:sobject:describe` is not returning fields if running user doesn't have FLS to the fields)
- Need details like whether field is `IsPermissionable` or `IsUpdatable` and etc. This information seems to be available only in this object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `QualifiedApiName` field from the `EntityParticle` itself.

```
SELECT  DataType,
        EntityDefinition.DeveloperName,
        IsCompound,
        DeveloperName,
        QualifiedApiName,
        FieldDefinition.QualifiedApiName 
FROM    EntityParticle 
WHERE   EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName ='Account'
```

does give you the individual field names, like `BillingStreet`, for each component particle of the compound field.